# Nginx rewrite always redirects

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get to work rewrite from `example.com/a/a23uy324` to `example.com/index.php/render?id=a23uy324` by this rewrite: 
`location ~ ^/a {
   rewrite ^/a/(.*)$  https://example.com/index.php/render?id=$1 break;
}` but any rule such as `last`, `break` or `permanent` - not making any effect. Site still redirects to PHP script. Please advise.

Here's full config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    return      301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /var/www/example.com/certificates/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/example.com/certificates/private.key;

    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    #works
    location ~ ^/a {
         rewrite ^/a/(.*)$  https://example.com/index.php/render?id=$1 break;
    }

    location ~* ^/(assets|files|robots\.txt) { }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?/$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/example.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 7d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is not very clear. You start by saying you want to rewrite, then you end by saying it does redirect. So it's not clear what you actually want to happen.

Comment: You have included `https://example.com` in the rewritten URI which make it "look" external. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Yes, I did this condition I mentioned in my config. But when I access `example.com/a/a23uy324` it redirects me to `example.com/index.php/render?id=a23uy324` - which is correct. But I don't want the user to see full URL. I want it remain the same (`example.com/a/a23uy324`)

Comment: I added a full config to be more clear. I also tried a lot of changes but it still shows redirect 301 on the server and keep redirects this URL. I tried try_files but never succeed in it too.